# Speakers don't work unless I plug the headphones in

Tags: 11.10, sound, headphones, speakers

I have this odd issue with my audio output. Speakers don't seem to work, however if I plug the headphones they work perfectly. Then, if I unplug the headphones, the speakers start to work again.

This all begun after I connected my laptop to a Roland Cube 60 amplifier through jack/mini jack adapter, but I have no idea how this can be related. I tried to play a bit with audio options but nothing worked out.

- This works in Windows so I know it's not a hardware problem.

Comment: I still have Windows and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/34423/3940) is a good starting point to troubleshoot audio (for me it was step 9).

Comment: Input? You mean the microphone? It looks ok.

Comment: @Takkat, I tried answer 8 from your link and it seems to work (sound starts without having to plug and unplug headphones), but now my audio widget is all messed up...

Comment: I took a look in audio preferences and it's empty. It's like devices are not recognized (but audio works).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is going to be in your sound configuration, accessible through the Sound Menu > Sound Preferences. Check that the speakers are enabled and that they are selected as the output.