# Missing sound volume icon on screen top (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, sound, icons, pulseaudio

I have recently installed a fresh ubuntu 14.04. But the volume icon is missing.

- I can hear all kinds of sounds (rythmbox, youtube videos,...) ...
- I have already tried to install the package **indicator-sound** and is already installed and updated.
- I can change the volume using the **alsamixer** command, but is not practical...

Any idea would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Joan, did any of the answers work?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1400275/1649110) answer your question?

Answer (score 55):

Execute in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

Comment: No such schema 'com.canonical.indicator.sound'

Comment: I got the same warning first, and after run cmd as below first then the cmd above can be executed : sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Do you have an idea why the icon can sometimes disappear?

Comment: Also works on 16.04.

Answer (score 37):

Go to **System Settings->Sound**. Then disable and re-enable the checkbox "Show sound volume in the menu bar" in the bottom left corner.

[image]

Comment: I can't see that button... I also doubt this will solve their problem, they have tried reinstalling etc...

Comment: In my case, this checkbox had been disabled after the upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10. So this helped me. Thank you the answer !

Answer (score 18):

In my case I removed and reinstalled pulseaudio because I was having issues with sound in Chrome. The solution to bring back the sound icon was the following:

1. From Cacus' answer above,run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
   ```
2. From Tomvo's answer above do:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
   ```
3. To make sure audio setting is available in control center do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
   ```
4. Logout and back in.

Comment: ...And the las line too! It solved my "empty" Settings problem. So two problems are solved. Now I still have to solve the soundcard-related problem - Dummy Output. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4):

You can try do this command:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
```

if not show restart Ubuntu :)

Comment: Thanks ! It worked !
I guess the sound icon disappeared when I uninstalled evolution from my Ubuntu...

Comment: That answer, worked but the problem rised again after computer restart.

Chceking my `/var/log/syslog` file... I found that error:

`Aug  3 00:39:06 joan-desktop pulseaudio[4077]: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: S’ha denegat el permís`

And finally I found the solution in this link [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33089/what-user-settings-control-audio-access)

Answer (score 1):

If your sound, wifi and bluetooth sensor are missing and you have Linux Studio or any other Linux that has the Xfwm4 window manager follow this instructions

1. Right-click on the top bar in any empty space and select **Panel** --> **Add New Items**

Here you have two options

2. Select **Indicator Plugin** or **Audio Mixer** or drag and place it in the top bar and now you can see it in the top right corner

[image]
[image]

[image: Right-click on the top bar in any empty space]
[image: Sound Icon now appears on the top right corner]

After you have added the panels that you need you can relocate them by location right-clicking on it an select **Move** to relocate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base* indicator-sound* libcanberra-pulse* osspd* osspd-pulseaudio* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11* unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon* webaccounts-extension-common* xul-ext-webaccounts*
```

see this link by Mythux
[See how to bring back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629634/after-reinstall-alsa-and-pulse-audio-system-setting-missing)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the icon theme often makes icons visible. But this may change your system appearance drastically.

Comment: in 15.10, different themes hide the icon on my desktop. I installed "unity-tweak-tool". Used the tool to select the Radiance theme with gnome-colours-common icons.  voila. sound icon reappeared.

Comment: I understand that the themes may hide icons and text (I have a problem with Ubuntu Software Center but...) the question was answered correctly in June 2014 - the OP never marked this post as having been correctly answered.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as a matter of record for others,

right-click on the top menu bar
select "Add to Panel" 
select "Indicator Applet Complete" from the list
click "Add", the close

Now the Volume Control is up there.

JohnJoe