# kubuntu 16.04: Sound card "access denied" error, can't play sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

I've checked out a dozen or more "solutions" (such as the one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483397/missing-sound-volume-icon-on-screen-top-14-04)), but my problem seems to go deeper than any of them.

It all started when I built wine.  I installed a few dozen `dev` and other packages.  I can reconstruct the list if necessary.  I rebooted and came back to the desktop and sound was gone.  I clicked the audio control icon and saw only "Dummy output" where previously my actual audio controller had been.

So I tried various suggestions I found online and the upshot was, even the audio icon disappeared.  Now my system can't even access my sound card:

```
$ lspci -v
[excerpt]
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio > Controller
  Subsystem: Lenovo 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller         
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
  Memory at f4700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
  sudo modprobe snd_hda_kernel
  modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_kernel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled `pulseaudio` and `alsa`, twice.  I even reinstalled the Linux image itself:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

None of this has made any difference.  Is there anything else I should try before reinstalling and forgetting I ever heard of wine?

Answer (score 0):

Two-part solution.  The first part I found by trial-and-error:

Removing the oss4 packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge oss4-base oss4-dev
```

restored my sound *immediately*.  I didn't even have to log out, much less reboot.  However, I still had no sound icon.

A search on that problem led me [here](https://ubuntuhut.wordpress.com/tag/kubuntu-missing-volume-icon-from-panel/), which told me to install package `kmix`.  I tried it.

It didn't restore the sound control panel I had -- it gave me something much superior to what I had!  I really like being able to control event sounds independent of the general device volume.

So I am back in business without having to reinstall. What a relief.

I am marking this as the Answer, but if someone comes forward with a more straightforward explanation or troubleshooting advice when the sound card is truly not seen even at the module level, I'll relocate the answer check mark.