# Continuous clicking noise during audio playback on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

Starting maybe 7 or 10 days ago, when I play back audio OR when I go to the 'settings/sound' control panel, I get a repetitive clicking sound (ca 2 Hz) in the audio output of my USB audio device. I do not get any clicking when playing audio from a browser window.

My USB audio device is a Behringer UM2, which has worked fine for well over a year.
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on Intel® Core™ i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
HDA Intel PCH Realtek ALC892
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.13.0-39-generic

Changing system volume using the control panel does not change the volume of the clicking.
Killing and restarting pulse audio with [pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload]
does not alter the clicking.  Changing channel volumes using alsamixer has no effect either.

I am guessing some Ubuntu update that I installed (I tend to install all of them as I am not literate enough to know how to be picky) screwed up the USB audio in some way.  Looking for ideas on how to get the sound working correctly again.  Or perhaps someone more knowledgeable can assure me I am SOL, and I can stop wasting time trying.  Either is good!

matigo's link, 1st answer, fixed my issue with minimum fuss.  Thanks Matigo!

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1400275/1222991) may give you what you need. The problem described in the question is slightly different, but there have been a number of audio-related issues reported lately that seem to be resolved with this type of solution 

Comment: These bug are usually triggered by kernel upgrades so I suggest you try older kernels (they're still ing grub) to see if the problem goes away

Comment: Thanks!  Matigo's link fixed the issue.  Again, THANKS!!!!

Comment: Hello. You should be aware there is no such version of Ubuntu as 20. There is 20.10 and 20.04 A question always needs a real version number.